# How to include internal script in the view in Play Framework

Tags: javascript, html, playframework-2.0

How do you add internal javascript using the  tags in a play framework view?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put `<script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("scripts_folder/your_script_name.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` to your view and you are done.